# Package "junit.framework" doesn't exist

Tags: java, junit, compilation

I'm a beginner to Java. I wrote a simple program, below one. But I am getting compilation errors.

**Java Class:**

```
  public class Return{
    public static int fibonacci(int n){
      if (n == 1 || n == 2){
        return 1;
      }
      return fibonacci(n - 1) + fibonacci(n - 2);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      System.out.println(fibonacci(6));
    }
  }
```

**Test File:**

```
import junit.framework.TestCase;

public class ReturnTest extends TestCase{
  public static  void testFibonacci(){
    assertEquals(1, Return.fibonacci(1));
    assertEquals(1, Return.fibonacci(2));
    assertEquals(1, Return.fibonacci(3));
  }
  public static void main(String[] args){
    testFibonacci();
  }
}
```

**Errors:**

```
`ReturnTest.java:1: error: package junit.framework does not exist
import junit.framework.TestCase;
                  ^
ReturnTest.java:3: error: cannot find symbol
public class ReturnTest extends TestCase{
                            ^
  symbol: class TestCase
ReturnTest.java:5: error: cannot find symbol
    assertEquals(1, Return.fibonacci(1));
    ^
  symbol:   method assertEquals(int,int)
  location: class ReturnTest
ReturnTest.java:6: error: cannot find symbol
    assertEquals(1, Return.fibonacci(2));
    ^
  symbol:   method assertEquals(int,int)
  location: class ReturnTest
ReturnTest.java:7: error: cannot find symbol
    assertEquals(1, Return.fibonacci(3));
    ^
  symbol:   method assertEquals(int,int)
  location: class ReturnTest
5 errors`
```

I googled for a solution but still stuck at that error. So please help me. What should I do now?

Comment: Please share the class Return from package statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add junit jar.It is missing.

You can download junit jar at https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit/4.11 and download the jar

or if you are using maven add the dependency in pom.